# What is the instance for the type?

Tags: haskell

The type signature from Monoid `mempty` function is:

```
*Exercises Data.Monoid> :t mempty
mempty :: Monoid a => a
```

When I look at the type signature for function(->) type on typeclass Monoid for `mempty` function it becomes to:

```
mempty :: Monoid b => a -> b
```

Because `a` will be replace through `a -> b`.

```
mempty :: Monoid a => a
mempty :: a -> b
```

I did not mention that `b` has to be a `Monoid`, otherwise the `mappend` function would not work.

Now I have following data type

```
newtype Combine a b = 
  Combine { unCombine :: a -> b }

instance (Semigroup b) 
  => Semigroup (Combine a b) where 
  Combine {unCombine=f} <> Combine {unCombine=g} = Combine (f <> g)

instance (Semigroup b, Monoid b)
  => Monoid (Combine a b) where
  mempty = Combine mempty
  mappend = (<>)
```

How the `mempty` function signature looks like for `Combine`?

So I am going to do exactly the same way as above:

The mempty declaration:

```
mempty :: Monoid a => a
```

`a` will be replace through Combine, then it becomes to:

```
mempty :: Combine a b
```

?

Comment: You forgot the constraint `Monoid b`. `mempty :: Monoid b => Combine a b`. `Combine a b` is just a wrapper for `a -> b`. So it is basically `Monoid b => a -> b` again. The part before the `=>` is the typeclass, which is replaced by the corresponding type dictionary at compile time. It tells the compiler how to produce a value of type `b`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not ask ghci? You have `mempty = Combine mempty`, so:

```
> :t Combine mempty
Combine mempty :: Monoid b => Combine a b
```

Therefore the type of `mempty` for `Combine` must be at least as specific as that.